# Scala Dependencies

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt

I just downloaded scala and trying to use the IntelliJ IDEA CE and having a number of dependency issues. I have been solving some of the dependancy issues by doing the following. Here is an example.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % "test"
```

was wondering what the correct way to add all of these dependencies is? I am also unsure about how to check the dependency tree before trying to run the file. I apologize if this is a straightforward question just want to make sure that I am adding the dependencies correctly since in the past (using other programming languages) badly adding dependencies has come back to haunt me.

```
{file:/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/Hello/}hello/testOnly demo.HelloTest
[info] Updating ...
[warn]  module not found: org.scalatest#scalatest_3.10;3.1.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/user1/.ivy2/local/org.scalatest/scalatest_3.10/3.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalatest/scalatest_3.10/3.1.0/scalatest_3.10-3.1.0.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /Users/user1/.sbt/preloaded/org.scalatest/scalatest_3.10/3.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////Users/user1/.sbt/preloaded/org/scalatest/scalatest_3.10/3.1.0/scalatest_3.10-3.1.0.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scalatest#scalatest_3.10;3.1.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.scalatest:scalatest_3.10:3.1.0 (/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/Hello/build.sbt#L7-8)
[warn]        +- default:hello_2.12:0.1
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scalatest#scalatest_3.10;3.1.0: not found
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve(IvyActions.scala:332)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEither$1(IvyActions.scala:208)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:239)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:204)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:70)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:199)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:196)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:238)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:193)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.ivy.IvyDependencyResolution.update(IvyDependencyResolution.scala:20)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:56)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:45)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:93)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$19(LibraryManagement.scala:106)
[error]     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:106)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:89)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:149)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:120)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2561)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:67)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:278)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scalatest#scalatest_3.10;3.1.0: not found
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed May 31, 2019, 2:29:57 PM
```

Thank you so much for your help. To reiterate what is the most correct way to download and manage Scale/IntelliJ IDEA CE dependencies?

Comment: You have your `scalaVersion` bad configured. It says it is searching for **3.10** that won't exists until the following ten years  _LOL_. The latest stable Scalar version is **2.12.8**. - Also, I believe ScalaTest **3.1.0** is still a beta, I think the stable one is **3.0.4**.

Comment: Latest stable _ScalaTest_ version is **3.0.7**.

Comment: Your example is correct and should not produce the error you show. Unresolved dependency `org.scalatest:scalatest_3.10:3.1.0` would be a scalatest version 3.1.0 for Scala 3.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a new plugin `addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.9.2")` . then you can `sbt dependencyTree`